# jquery show hide div on mouse over

Tags: jquery

i am trying to learn jquery.
please help me with this problem
i need to show a div which appears on hover of any element like menu item and remains appeared unless the mouse is either on the element from which it is appeared or in the div itself.
the div gets hide when the mouse is no on the div itself or the element

here is an example [adityabirla menu](http://www.adityabirla.com/)
where the div submenu appears on mouseover of about us and other and gets disappeared when the mouse is not in submenu or aboutus link

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried doing it..??

Comment: What you are describing is actually pretty simple, but understand that we are not here to do your work for you. Post your code (and please, do the code), and we will help where we can.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like;

```
$("#div2").hide();
$( "#div1" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $("#div2").show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $("#div2").hide();
});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8guKx/)** is a working demo.